# Angular Dart Routing causes Blank Screen With No Errors

Tags: angular, firebase, dart, angular-dart

I am trying to use the Angular Dart Sample Tour of Heroes as a model for a WebApp I am trying to build.

I am changing it to use FireBase as the data provider instead of the mockClients.

This is the app component:

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart';
import 'package:firebase/firestore.dart' as fs;
import 'src/todo_list/hero.dart';
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';
import 'src/todo_list/routes.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['app_component.css'],
  template: '''
  <h1>This is the title</h1>
  <router-outlet [routes]="Routes.all"></router-outlet>
  ''',
  directives: [coreDirectives, routerDirectives],
  exports: [RoutePaths, Routes],

)
class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  List<Hero> heroes = [];

  //REDACTED HERE, BUT FIREBASE SHOWN TO BE WORKING BEFORE ADDING ROUTING
  @override
  ngOnInit() {
    initializeApp(
    apiKey: "* * * * * * * *",
    authDomain: "* * * * * * * *",
    databaseURL: "* * * * * * * * *",
    projectId: "* * * * * * * * *",
    storageBucket: "* * * * * * ",
    messagingSenderId: "* * * * * * "
);

//Database db = database();
//DatabaseReference ref = db.ref('items');

fs.Firestore store = firestore();
fs.CollectionReference ref = store.collection("items");

  ref.onSnapshot.listen((querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) {
     if (change.type == "added") {
       var docSnapshot = change.doc;
       var id = docSnapshot.data()['id'];
       var name = docSnapshot.data()["name"];
       var full = docSnapshot.data()["pickupNeeded"];
       var item = new Hero(id, name, full);
       heroes.insert(0, item);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

It seems like the problem has something to do with the injector on main.dart as that is when the app broke.

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/app_component.template.dart';
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';

import 'main.template.dart' as self;

@GenerateInjector(
  routerProvidersHash,
)
final InjectorFactory injector = self.injector;

void main() {
  runApp(AppComponentNgFactory, createInjector: injector);
}
```

I noticed that the AngularDart Tour of Heroes Example app doesn't have "Injectable()" on any classes, but other Samples apps do.

What am I missing? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has similar problems, it seemed that the best solution was to move the firebase initialization to the main.dart file.

Furthermore, I created a Firebase Service to handle the Firebase part of things.

The actual creation of a list from Firebase was moved to a Dashboard Component that was displayed in the app component.

Separating everything out solved the issue.